# Configure Raspberry PI Access Point to use RADIUS Apache Authentication?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I made a Raspberry PI into a wireless access point using `isc-dhcp-server` and `hostapd`, which is cool. What I would like to do is add a web-page authentication form for the network where I could display things such as terms of services, etc.

In my reading I have found that the way to do this is using a RADIUS server. I installed freeradius, and it says everything is working correctly, but I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to configure my DHCP server to know that RADIUS should handle authentication.

I have a feeling that I will have to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file somehow to make the switch, but I only partially understood the documentation I found in `man interfaces`.

How can I set up a web authentication module? Possibly with a database where I could use a PHP interface to log in users, but not necessary for now. Just looking for some info to get me started. Any helpful resources, guides, tutorials, blog posts, and other info would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Resources I've used

- https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software
- http://binaryheartbeat.blogspot.com/2013/12/raspberry-pi-based-freeradius-server.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RADIUS is commonly used as a way for an AP to use WPA2-Enterprise (802.1X) authentication, but outsource the actual AP-side authentication to a separate server (the RADIUS server). You configure it in `hostapd`'s conf file. It has nothing to do with DHCP or your `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Web-based authentication (also called "Captive Portal") is a separate concept, and it's pretty much mutually exclusive with WPA2-Enterprise. Web based authentication requires that you let clients on basically without authentication, so that they have enough network connectivity that they can get redirected to a web server. Web-based authentication really doesn't have anything to do with DHCP either, although you probably want to have a DHCP server on your network so that the wireless clients get an IP address lease via DHCP so that they have enough network connectivity to try to reach a web server.

If you want to do web-based authentication but use a separate authentication server, you would configure your AP for Captive Portal mode, and then you would set up your web server to provide an authentication UI, and relay that authentication attempt to a separate authentication server. However, the in the web server world, it's much more common to use LDAP, not RADIUS, as the remote authentication protocol.

Comment: Wow, I have so much to learn about networking! "Captive Portal" was the magic phrase I was looking for! Thank you!